# sapui5/openui5 TreeTable with custom control column throwing duplicate id error when expanding a node

Tags: duplicates, custom-controls, sapui5, renderer, treetable

I have a `sap.ui.table.TreeTable` with several columns, one of which contains a custom control defined as a template for the column.

The TreeTable renders correctly, and the column with the custom control also renders and functions correctly ... that is until I expand an unexpanded node.

When I expand a node the Renderer throws an error
`Error: adding element with duplicate id '__link0-col1-row0'`,
which is the column associated with the custom control.

I can workaround the problem by adding **attachToggleOpenState** event handler which destroys this columns template and adds it again. Expensive but it works!

```js
this.oTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable("myTable", {
    columns : [ new sap.ui.table.Column( {
        label : "Query",
        template : new sparqlish.control.queryClause({
            clausePath : {
                path : "viewModel>path"
            }
        }),
        visible : true,
        width : "500px"
    }), ],
}).attachToggleOpenState(function(oEvent) {
    // TODO workaround as expanding Tree causes duplicate id
    var queryColumn = oEvent.getSource().getColumns()[0];
    queryColumn.destroyTemplate();
    queryColumn.setTemplate(new sparqlish.control.queryClause({
        clausePath : {
            path : "viewModel>path"
        }
    }))
});
```

sparqlish.control.queryClause is the custom control.

I am using openui5 version 1.28.15

Any other, less expensive, suggestions?

The custom control takes this form, however this control invokes other controls and so on.

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.conceptClause");
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.propertyClause");
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.conjunctionPropertyClause");
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("sparqlish.control.queryClause", {
    metadata : {
        properties : {
            clausePath : {
                type : "string"
            }
        },
        events : {},
        aggregations : {
            _conceptClause : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.conceptClause",
                multiple : false
            },
            _propertyClause : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.propertyClause",
                multiple : false
            },
            _conjunctionPropertyClause : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.conjunctionPropertyClause",
                multiple : false
            }
        }
    },
    init : function() {
        var self = this;
        self.setAggregation("_conceptClause", new sparqlish.control.conceptClause());
        self.setAggregation("_propertyClause", new sparqlish.control.propertyClause());
        self.setAggregation("_conjunctionPropertyClause", new sparqlish.control.conjunctionPropertyClause());
    },
    renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {
        if (oControl.getClausePath() != undefined) {
            // TODO no point if path not yet defined
            oRm.write("<div ");
            oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
            oRm.writeClasses();
            oRm.write(">");
            var currentModel = oControl.getModel("queryModel");
            // Set binding context, rather than just the binding path etc, as this seems essential for satisfactory binding of
            // aggregations
            oControl.setBindingContext(new sap.ui.model.Context(oQueryModel, oControl.getClausePath()), "queryModel")
            var currentCtx = oControl.getBindingContext("queryModel");
            var currentContext = oControl.getModel("queryModel").getProperty("", currentCtx);
            if (currentContext != undefined) {
                var sClass = currentContext._class;
                if (sClass == "Query") {
                    oControl.setAggregation("_conceptClause", new sparqlish.control.conceptClause().setBindingContext(oControl.getBindingContext("queryModel")));
                    oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_conceptClause"));
                } else if (sClass == "Clause") {
                    oControl.setAggregation("_propertyClause", new sparqlish.control.propertyClause().setBindingContext(oControl.getBindingContext("queryModel")));
                    oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_propertyClause"));
                } else if (sClass == "ConjunctionClause") {
                    oControl.setAggregation("_conjunctionPropertyClause", new sparqlish.control.conjunctionPropertyClause().setBindingContext(oControl
                            .getBindingContext("queryModel")));
                    oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_conjunctionPropertyClause"));
                } else {
                    jQuery.sap.log.fatal("Incorrect class of provided query clause");
                }
            }
            oRm.write("</div>");
        } else {
            jQuery.sap.log.fatal("clausePath not defined");
        }
    }
});
```

An example of one of the dependent controls is below.

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.conceptMenu");
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.conceptFilters");
jQuery.sap.require("sparqlish.control.addClause");
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("sparqlish.control.conceptClause", {
    metadata : {
        properties : {
            concept : "object"
        },
        events : {},
        aggregations : {
            _concept : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.conceptMenu",
                multiple : false
            },
            _conceptFilters : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.conceptFilters",
                multiple : false
            },
            _addClause : {
                type : "sparqlish.control.addClause",
                multiple : false
            }
        }
    },
    init : function() {
        var self = this;
        var conceptSelect =function(oEvent){

                var currentModel = self.getModel("queryModel");
                var currentContext = self.getBindingContext("queryModel");
                var currentModelData = currentModel.getProperty("", currentContext);
                currentModelData.conceptFilters = [];
                currentModelData.clauses = {};
                var sConcept = oEvent.getParameter("concept");
                var oMetaModel = self.getModel("metaModel");
                var oConcept=oMetaModel.getODataEntitySet(sConcept);
                self.setConcept( oConcept);
                self.oEntityTypeModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                self.oEntityTypeModel.setData(oMetaModel.getODataEntityType(oConcept.entityType));
                self.setModel(self.oEntityTypeModel, "entityTypeModel");
                self.getAggregation("_conceptFilters").setModel(self.oEntityTypeModel, "entityTypeModel");

                self.getAggregation("_conceptFilters").getAggregation("_extendFilter").setVisible(true);
                currentModel.refresh();
                self.rerender();    
        };
        self.setAggregation("_concept", new sparqlish.control.conceptMenu({
            selected : function(oEvent) {
                self.getAggregation("_conceptFilters").getAggregation("_extendFilter").setVisible(true);
            },
            changed : conceptSelect
        }).bindElement("queryModel>"));
        self.setAggregation("_conceptFilters", new sparqlish.control.conceptFilters().bindElement("queryModel>"));
        self.setAggregation("_addClause", new sparqlish.control.addClause({
            pressed : function(oEvent) {
                alert("concept");
            }
        }).bindElement("queryModel>"));
    },

    renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {
        oRm.addClass("conceptClause");
        oRm.write("<div ");
        oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
        oRm.writeClasses();
        oRm.write(">");
        oRm.write(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18nModel").getProperty("conceptClauseFind"));
        oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_concept"));
        oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_conceptFilters"));
        oRm.write("&nbsp;");
        oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_addClause"));
        oRm.write("</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant soruce code to the question.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of your custom control.

Comment: Also added the outline of the control. However this is the root of a number of controls which would be too extensive to share is Stackoverflow. This control has been thoroughly tested outside of the TreeTable.

Comment: I was expecting to find a fixed id assigned to the column, the template or one of its subcontrols which raises the Error, but according to your snippet this looks fine. Do you have a `Link` in one of your subcontrols?

Comment: Added an example. (corrected to removed comment about factory function. Wrong control!)